# Will having code modularized affect the preformance of the react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an React app from the client. This app contains one *index.jsx*.
**90%** of coding done here.

To avoid the Scroll Limbo. I Started modularizing the code for each requirement.

functionalities like MODAL, MATERIAL-UI, component handlers etc.,

Some modules such as ROUTERS are seperated by default.

This is what I done and I'm new to React.

Will these affect the performance?

Comment: Note that even *if* that affected performance you should still separate the file, it is cleaner. Unless you have some actual performance problems there is no point optimizing these kind of things.

Comment: The answer to this is far too dependent on information you haven't shared that will be specific to your situation. For instance, are you bundling afterward, or relying on the browser to load the modules itself? Over HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2? How *many* modules? How deep is the nesting? Startup performance, or ongoing performance? Etc. etc. This isn't the kind of question that fits SO's Q&A format.

Comment: FWIW, if you're not bundling after having split it into modules, [this article](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ovo4PurT_1K4WFwN2MYmmgbLcr7v6DRQN67ESVA-wq0/pub) from a couple of years ago may be useful reading.

Comment: [Obligatory link to Eric Lippert's rant on performance questions](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Basically, measure it and see if it affects performance in your circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt moving stuff around will improve the performance of the software. But, definitely, having tidy code and a tidy project will improve **YOUR performance** while working/coding.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not affect performance in any noticeable way, and in some cases can actually [*improve*](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) it. However, as one commenter pointed out, this question is very broad and you would need to get a little more specific with use-cases.

Comment: I Can't share the code. They're yet to include HTTP's & Redux Stuffs. But I Guarantee the Lifecycle methods are mimiced in Hooks properly. So, If they wanna in HTTP's & Other new concepts. They should strain more.

Anyways Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

No this will not affect the performance. I see you have mentioned a `.jsx` extension. That means you are writing React using JSX syntax. Browsers don't understand JSX syntax at all. That logically just means that you are using a bundler (webpack I'm assuming). A bundler's job is to traverse your source code starting from the `index.js(x)` file and "bundle" the files into 1 big executable. That means that regardless if your source code was comprosied 10 files or one huge `index.jsx` file, it will be bundled into approximately the same executable with similar performance.

This was a long way of say 'no' but hope you got something out of the explanation